# Form type select with multiple values

Tags: forms

I have a form field with type select. The results values are taken from the database.
If the select list is with single value I'm displaying the value title on the submit like this:

```
   $selected_index = $form_state['values']['select_list']; //the field is select_list
   $display_value = form['select_list']['#options'][$selected_index];
   dpm($display_value); //it's showing the selected option value title.
```

When I'm using `'#multiple' => TRUE`; into the form field, It's showing error: Warning: Illegal offset type in...

How can I display the titles of the multiple values?

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
function mymodule_page($form, &$form_state) {

global $user; 

$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created
FROM {node} n WHERE n.uid = :uid and type = :type', array(':uid' => $user->uid, ':type' => 'outlets'));

$droplist = array();
foreach($result as $record) {
    $title = $record->title;
    array_push($droplist, $title); 

    $form['select_list'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => 'Select list',
       '#options' => $droplist, //I'm getting this list from my database
       '#multiple' => TRUE,   
   );
}

function mymodule_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $selected_index = $form_state['values']['select_list'];

   foreach($selected_index as $key => $sindex)
   dpm($sindex);
}
```

Comment: please dpm($form_state['values']['select_list']) in submit and get snap shot of nested row. tnx

Comment: Here's a screenshot http://imageshack.com/a/img827/3339/4vea.jpg

Comment: This is when a select the second and third options in the list.

Comment: according to screenshot it is correct to return 1,2 to you !!! the  title of your nodes are `1` and `2` !!! .

Comment: Yes, but how do I print as title, not integers? Please read the main thread.   
Later I have to send the value details on email. Integer's wont do the job

Comment: I dont understand what you want do with them, as you see in your screenshot '1' is string not integer !!!, please explain me what you want to do with these titles?

Comment: In the website every user with role "seller" will be able to see his/her stores, but cannot create a new stores. Only admin will be able to do that. In the form will be able to select the stores/options from the drop list. The stores are displayed by the specific author of the nodes/stores. that's why I'm getting the information from the database.  After sending the form, the admin will receive an email of this form. In that email has to be displayed the names of the options that user selected, not the numbers.

Comment: Let's say the seller John has three stores, so on the user page with the form the drop list will display his three stores. Hi will be able to create an offer that is for some of his stores, so he can mark which stores will get that offer. After sending the form, the admin will know what stores are for the specific offer. I'll say this again, if options are displayed in the email as number, the admin wont know for which stores means. I hope its clear.

Comment: ok, I got it, but you content title is '1' and '2' , got to your content  in `/admin/content` , find content with title '1' and '2'  , edit their titles, and you will see that the  result of code not be integer . **your problem is your content titles not your code**, edit them

Comment: The titles are fine and not with numbers, otherwise I wont see them in the drop list, but will show only numbers.

Comment: There's something related with $form_state, but I still didn't find an answer.

Comment: in foreach `dpm($record->title)`, you will see they are number!!!, if you see in drop down list they are integer (check html source and see the value of them also number )

Comment: No, when I put dpm($record->title); in foreach it's showing their titles, not numbers. On the html source is like this: <option value="0">storename</option> etc.Thats why I'm using array_push there and its displaying correctly.

Comment: I think we should continue this in a chat, so I'll show you more details if you need.

Answer (score 2):

In case of multiple values, the return value is an array of all selected values. Therefore, `$selected_index` is now an array and not a string.

Comment: Well, then how do I display the values, because I want to send them with drupal_mail later?

Answer (score -1):

When you use `multiple` the value of field  is array instead of only one value 
you can get them :

```
  $selected_index = $form_state['values']['select_list']['und']; //the field is select_list
  $values=array();
  foreach(  $selected_index as $sindex){
   $values=$sindex['value'];
   //dsm($sindex['value']);
}
```

Comment: Zhilevan, thank you for your answer. The dpm($sindex) is showing the values like (0,1,2..) I want to show them as titles.

Comment: Show us the code for the select field if you please.

Comment: Something like `$selected = array_intersect_key(array_filter($form_state['values']['select_list']), $form['select_list']['#options']);` will get you a filtered array of selected values, from there you can display it however you need

Comment: Wtower, I've edited my thread.

Comment: @user2519032 I update my answer

Comment: I've tried your code. "$selected_index = $form_state['values']['select_list']['und']" [und] doesn't exist in this line and it shows error "Undefined index...". I've removed ['und'] and copy the other part of the code, but it still shows only integers, not the title.

Comment: please write what is `$droplist`?

Comment: I've just added that in main thread.

Comment: is it possible get snapshot of results you say(dpm result,please collapse all row of it)?
I am sure you have a mistake